# Kaa - Log Appender Instantiation

Tags: kaa

When does a Log Appender class get instantiated within Kaa ? Is there a default scope for the Log Appender instance ? Is the Log Appender class gets instantiated for each request ? Is there a pool of Log Appender instances servicing the request ?

Answer (score 0):

Log appender is immediately instantiated once you create it on Admin UI. And it's lazy (when the first log comes) instantiated after server restarting. Each Kaa node has only one instance of particular log appender.